# Polymorphism and forms in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I've been full of questions lately, but thanks to this awesome community, I'm learning a ton.

I got all the help I needed with polymorphic associations earlier and now I have a question about tackling forms with polymorphic models.  For instance I have Phoneable and User, so when I create my form to register a user, I want to be able to assign a few phone numbers to the user (ie: cell, work, home).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, :as => :phoneable
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phoneable, :polymorphic => true
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  t.column :name, :string
  t.references :phoneable, :polymorphic => true
end

class CreatePhones < ActiveRecord::Migration
  t.column :area_code, :integer
  t.column :number, :integer
  t.column :type, :string
  t.references :phoneable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now when I create my form, I'm getting confused.  Normally I would do the following:

```
- form_for :user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |form|
  %fieldset
    %label{:for => "name"} Name:
    = form.text_field :name
    ##now how do I go about adding a phone number?
    ##typically I'd do this:
    ##%label{:for => "phone"} Phone:
    ##= form.text_field :phone
```

Using polymorphism, would I just approach the same way, but use fields_for?

```
- user_form.fields_for :phone do |phone| %>
  %label{for => "area_code"} Area Code:
  = phone.text_field :area_code
  %label{for => "number"} Number:
  = phone.text_field :number
```

Is this the correct approach in this instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before we go further, I did notice one issue - you do not need the `t.references` with the `has_many` side of the association.  So you do not need it in the `create_user` model.  What that does is it creates the `phonable_id` and the `phoneable_type` columns, you only need that in the polymorphic model.

You are heading down the correct path with the `fields_for` approach.  But in order to get that working, you need to tell the model how to handle those fields.  You do that with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` class method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, :as => :phoneable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones
end
```

and one minor thing, you will need to have the `fields_for` point to the *exact* name of the association

```
- form_for @user do |user_form|
  - user_form.fields_for :phones do |phone|
```

Instead of

```
- form_for @user do |user_form|
  - user_form.fields_for :phone do |phone|
```

and make sure you remove your stray `%>` erb tag :)

More on `accepts_nested_attributes_for`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer and a huge thanks for the help!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Just to clarify though, before I run into any problems.  In my createUsers, I don't need to include a column for phones?  ie: t.column :phone, :phoneable

Or something along those lines?

Comment: No, it is just like any other has_many relationship, it uses the foreign keys of the polymorphic table in the join.