# Can't save nested model on polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Forced to ask for help with saving nested models on polymorphic association. I'm missing something but can't figure out what.
Everithing pretty straightforward. There is Address which can have multiple Phones.
So models are

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base      
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, allow_destroy: true  
  validates :city, :street, :building, :name, presence: true  
end
```

and

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :phoneable, polymorphic: true  
  validates :number, :extension, presence: true        
end
```

**addresses_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @address = Address.new
  @phone = @address.phones.build
  authorize @address
end

def create
  @address = Address.create(address_params)
  authorize @address
  if @address.save
    binding.pry
    flash[:success] = "Address #{@address.name} created"
    redirect_to address_path(@address)
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Failed'
    render :new
  end
end

 def address_params
     params.require(:address).permit(:name, :street, :building, :city, phones_attributes: [:id, :number, :extension, :details] )
 end
```

**/app/views/address.html.erb**

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= form_for(@address, html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'}) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @address, model_name: 'addresses' %>
          <div id="create-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="control-label col-md-4">
                <%= f.label :city, 'Город' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.select(:city, options_for_select(['Moscow', 'Samara']), {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="control-label col-md-4">
                <%= f.label :street, 'Street' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.text_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="control-label col-md-4">
                <%= f.label :building, 'Building' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.text_field :building, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="control-label col-md-4">
                <%= f.label :name, 'Place name' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="control-label col-md-4">
                <%= f.label :phones, 'Phone' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= f.fields_for :phone do |phone_form| %>
                  <%= phone_form.text_field :number, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="control-label col-md-4">
                <%= phone_form.label :extension, 'Ext.' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= phone_form.text_field :extension, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class='col-md-offset-4 col-md-6'>
                <%= f.submit @address.new_record? ? 'Add' : 'Update', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

First issue I encountered with is if I set key `:phones` instead `:phone` into the following line `<%= f.fields_for :phone do |phone_form| %>` my phone text fields don't render in view but they should. One user emphasized this moment here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3328041/2049476
if I use `:phone` everything somehow works fine but seems like it's wrong.
And the second one.
Phone object doesn't save in DB, when I create new address or edit current I succeed but phone doesn't show any validation errors if I leave all it fields blank.
Here what I have in `params` hash

`{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"inwXr3Ev/Aj/hZRY2IadizDHDgdSFo2zFhY9DAvysfFu3jjD9AS66esKVsTzEuKo2WC46YQt6HnOKTgInvfUEg==",
 "address"=>{"city"=>"Moscow", "street"=>"ul. Tsentralnaya d. 4 kv. 220", "building"=>"1212", "name"=>"Astoria", "phone"=>{"number"=>"9215555555", "extension"=>"111"}},
 "commit"=>"Add",
 "controller"=>"addresses",
 "action"=>"create"}`

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index

Comment: 2. pass not a `phone` via params. but `phones_attributes` array of hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try answer for 2 issues:

1. The correct way is to pass `:phones`, and then `phone` as variable to `field_for`, like is was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index):

   ```
   <%- @address.phones.each.with_index do |phone, index| %>
      <%- f.fields_for :phones, phone do |phone_form| %>  

      <%- end %>
   <%- end %>
   ```
2. Should be resolved as of the 1-st question, since the fields shoudl sent ot server via `params` not a `phone` hash, but `phones_attributes` array of hashes, in order to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` could accept phones:

   ```
   phones_attributes: [{ ... },{ ... }]
   ```

Comment: You saved my day! Everything works now. Thanks a lot. All the best!